# Representation of $V$ as $\mathbb{C}^{2}$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, analysis, vector-spaces, representation-theory

Let $V$ be a finite-dimensional complex inner product space and suppose that there is an operator (a matrix) $A$ on $V$ that satisfies the following anti-commutation relations:
$$AA + AA = 0$$
$$A^{*}A + AA^{*} = I,$$
where $I$ is the identity matrix and $A^{*}$ is the adjoint of $A$. In this case, one can show that $V$ has an even dimension and that $A$ has a representation as a $2 \times 2$ matrix:
$$A = \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 
\end{pmatrix}
\tag{1}\label{1}
$$
This is done in [Simon's book](https://www.jstor.org/stable/j.ctt7ztwsn). The basic idea is that $V$ has an orthogonal direct sum decomposition $V = \operatorname{Ker}(A) \oplus \operatorname{Ker}(A^{*})$ and, thus, every vector $\phi \in V$ can be seen as a vector:
$$\phi = \begin{pmatrix}
\varphi \\
\psi
\end{pmatrix}
\tag{2}\label{2}$$
with $\varphi \in \operatorname{Ker}(A)$ and $\psi \in \operatorname{Ker}(A^{*})$. In this case, $A$ acts as a $2 \times 2$ matrix on these vectors.

I have some questions regarding some terminology and concepts written on Simon's book.

- First, I suppose the representation (\ref{1}) should be, strictly speaking,
  $$A = \begin{pmatrix}
  0 & I \\
  0 & 0
  \end{pmatrix}
  $$
  that is, with $1$ replaced by the identity matrix $I$ on $V$, but then I can simply see $I$ as $1$ in some sense. This is fine. The terminology "representation" (as in $A$ has a representation...) is a bit more troublesome. A representation of a group $G$ in a vector space $U$ is a group homomorphism $\rho: G \to \operatorname{GL}(U)$. Of course, the space of all linear operators (i.e. complex matrices) on $V$ is a group, and we can talk about a representation of these matrices on $U = \mathbb{C}^{2}$. But the above setting only deals with *one* matrix $A$, not *all of them*, so I am a bit confused with the usage of the term representation in this context. Does it have any rigorous meaning or it is just a way of writing $A$ can be informally seen as the right hand side of (\ref{1})?
- More importantly, Simon seems to imply that the "representation" of $A$ as the $2 \times 2$ matrix in (\ref{1}) imply that $V$ itself can be viewed as $\mathbb{C}^{2}$. This is very confusing to me. On one hand, it makes sense because $A$ can be seen as a $2 \times 2$ matrix, so it should act on elements of $\mathbb{C}^{2}$. However, the only decomposition of vectors of $V$ being used is (\ref{2}), and it is absolutely not clear why this can be seen as $\mathbb{C}^{2}$ if each entry $\varphi$ and $\psi$ is not uniquely determined by a complex number (that is, $\phi$ in (\ref{2}) is not a a vector on $\mathbb{C}^{2}$).

Can someone please help me with finding the right definitions of the concepts being used by Simon and justifying its way of seing $V$ as $\mathbb{C}^{2}$?

Comment: A stepping stone is taking a basis $(v_1, \ldots, v_n, w_1, \ldots, w_n)$ where the $v_i$ are a basis for $\ker A$ and the $w_i$ are a basis for $\ker A^*$. Then the matrix of $A$ relative to this basis will be something like $\begin{pmatrix}0 & I \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$. There is another whole thing you can do with notation where you can treat operators between direct sums like elements, which is basically just a fancy way of doing what I described with fewer notation.

Comment: @Joppy but then why is the underlying space still viewed as $\mathbb{C}^{2}$? It makes sense to me to treat operators between direct sum like elements, but treating the space as $\mathbb{C}^{2}$ still seems odd given that you don't have a natural identification.

Comment: The space is not treated as $\mathbb{C}^2$. If we have a linear map $T: U \oplus V \to X \oplus Y$, then $T$ may be written as $T = \begin{pmatrix} T_{XU} & T_{XV} \\ T_{YU} & T_{YV} \end{pmatrix}$, where for instance $T_{XU}$ is a linear map $U \to X$.

Comment: Now also crossposted at MathOverflow: https://mathoverflow.net/q/467516/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you note on MO, [algebras](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebra_representation), as well as [groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_representation), have representations.  One way to view Simon's claim is that we are taking a [$*$-representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gelfand%E2%80%93Naimark%E2%80%93Segal_construction#States_and_representations) of the [$*$-algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/*-algebra) (i.e., algebra with complex-anti-linear anti-involution) $\mathcal A = \mathbb C\langle A, A^*\rangle/(A^2 = 0, A^{*\,2} = 0, A^* A + A A^* = 1)$—where $A$ and $A^*$ are treated as formal symbols, subject only to the requirement that the involution on $\mathcal A$ takes $A$ to $A^*$ and the further relations by which we quotient—in the sense that it is acting on an inner-product space (not just an abstract vector space) $V$ by a (unital) homomorphism $\pi : \mathcal A \to \operatorname{End}(V)$ such that $\pi(x^*)$ equals $\pi(x)^*$ for all $x \in \mathcal A$ (which, in this case, is equivalent to just requiring that $\pi(A^*)$ equals $\pi(A)^*$).  This is what he means by referring to “a representation of (II.6.1–2)”, *not* a representation of $\operatorname{End}(V)$.  (Simon leaves out the relation $A^{*\,2} = 0 \iff \{A^*, A^*\} = 0$, presumably viewing it as a formal consequence of $\{A, A\} = 0$.)  Then Simon's claim (which you [clarified](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/comments/1213717) on MO is on [pp. 137–138 of Chapter II](https://www.jstor.org/stable/j.ctt7ztwsn.5?seq=43)) is that, for any such homomorphism,

1. $V$ is even-dimensional;
2. if $V$ is $2$-dimensional, then there is an orthonormal basis of $V$ with respect to which the map to $\operatorname{End}(V) \cong \operatorname M_{2\times2}(\mathbb C)$ is identified with \eqref{1} (really $2\times2$ matrices, not $2\dim(V)\times2\dim(V)$ matrices); and
3. in general, we can decompose $V$ as a direct sum of copies of \eqref{1}.

Point 3 implies Point 1, so we could omit that, but it's probably worth stating explicitly.  We could also state Point 3 by saying that there is a(n orthogonal, non-unique) decomposition $V = V^+ + V^-$ such that $A \mapsto \begin{pmatrix} 0 & T \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$, $A^* \mapsto \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ T^* & 0 \end{pmatrix}$, where $T : V^- \to V^+$ is an isomorphism; but it wouldn't really make sense to ask whether $T$ is the identity, since it's a map between different spaces (as @Joppy said in the [comments](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/posts/comments/10417209)).

Comment: LSpice, thanks! Now everything is much clearer! I just want to clarify a few minor things. First, your definition of $\mathcal{A}$, $A$ is *not* an operator, right? Rather, it is just an element of an abstract algebra, but you used the same notation because it is identified with the fermionic operator $A$ under $\pi$. Is this correct? Also, why take the quotient space and not simply the unital algebra generated by $A$ and $A^{*}$?

Comment: Another thing is point 3. What does it mean for $V$ to be a direct sum of matrices? The way I see it, if $\text{dim}V = 2m$, then $V$ is isomorphic to $\bigoplus_{i=1}^{m}\mathbb{C}^{2}$, so $\pi: \mathcal{A} \to \text{End}(V) \cong \text{End}(\bigoplus_{i=1}^{m}\mathbb{C}^{2})$. Hence, $V$ has a basis in which $\rho(A)$, seen as an operator on $\text{End}(\bigoplus_{i=1}^{m}\mathbb{C}^{2})$, is the direct sum of (\ref{1}). Is this correct?

Comment: @Idontgetit, your [second comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/10428718) is correct, although note that "Hence …" is not a formal consequence; it is the content of the proposition preceding Simon's remark.  This is the notion of [direct sum of representations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_sum#Direct_sum_of_group_representations) to which I was implicitly appealing.

Comment: @Idontgetit, your [first comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/10428713) is also correct about the meaning of $A$ in the algebra $\mathcal A$.  (In some sense, the content of the proposition is that we would lose no information about $\mathcal A$ if we literally defined it to be the subalgebra $\mathbb C\left[\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\&0\end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix}0\\1&0\end{pmatrix}\right]$ of $\operatorname M_{2\times2}(\mathbb C)$, but I haven't done that.)  If I didn't take the quotient, then I'd have to speak of […](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/10428780)

Comment: […](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/10428775) $*$-representations $\pi$ of the free $*$-algebra $\mathbb C[A, A^*]$ on one generator satisfying the additional conditions that $\{\pi(A), \pi(A)\}$ equals $0$ and $\{\pi(A), \pi(A^*)\}$ equals the identity.  There's nothing wrong with doing so, but defining $\mathcal A$ to be a quotient as I've done removes the need for those extra conditions by building them into the algebra.

Comment: @Idontgetit, I remembered that $\mathbb C[A, A^*]$ is usually used when adjoining *commuting* indeterminates.  Since I definitely do not want to assume that $A$ and $A^*$ commute, I changed it to $\mathbb C\langle A, A^*\rangle$. Now my "lose no information" [comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/10428775) is saying that the obvious map from $\mathbb C\langle A, A^*\rangle$ to the algebra generated by $\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\&0\end{pmatrix}$ and its adjoint factors through an isomorphism with $\mathcal A$.